# Function that finds the first negative number in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write a function in Excel that finds the first negative number in a column and then returns the cells next to this number. For example

```
A    B
1    1
2    56
3    7
4    -3
5    -4
6    -20
7    -50
```

What I wrote is:

```
{=INDEX(B1:B7,MATCH(TRUE,B1:B7<0),1)}
```

But this finds the smallest number in column B.

I want a function that finds the first negative, in this case -3, and then gives me the number in A4 (4).

Also I need it to work with empty cells. I mean I want that the area is for example B1:B200, but it only looks the cells with values in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Longer answer but doesn't need entering as an array

```
=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B1:B7<0,0,1),0))
```